# Why is my label field is giving me an error in this c# code

Tags: c#, label

Im kinda new to c# so if somebody please tell me why im getting an error

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lblTaskManager.Text = null;
        RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
               @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System");
            try
            {
                if (objRegistryKey.GetValue("DisableTaskMgr") == null)
                    objRegistryKey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", "1");
                lblTaskManager.Text = ("Disabled");

            else
                objRegistryKey.DeleteValue("DisableTaskMgr");
                objRegistryKey.Close();
                lblTaskManager.Text = ("Enabled");
            }
            catch
            { }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is at ("Disabled"); it suggests that a } is required but adding that does not change anything. And also how can I avoid this error in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Use { } correct with if:

```
            if (objRegistryKey.GetValue("DisableTaskMgr") == null)
            {
                objRegistryKey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", "1");
                lblTaskManager.Text = ("Disabled");
            }
            else
            {
                objRegistryKey.DeleteValue("DisableTaskMgr");
                objRegistryKey.Close();
                lblTaskManager.Text = ("Enabled");
            }
```

The ( ) are not needed but shouldn´t harm your code.

And maybe you should move the **objRegistryKey.Close();** to the finally of the try catch.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

1. Put `RegistryKey` creation into `using` and drop explict `Close()`.
2. Add `{}` after `if` and `else`.
3. Remove `()` around the strings assigned.
4. Drop that nightmare `try { ... } catch {}` (ignore *all* exceptions thrown) and never ever use such code again.

Something like this:

```
  using (RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
           "@Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System")) {
    if (objRegistryKey.GetValue("DisableTaskMgr") == null) {
      objRegistryKey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", "1");
      lblTaskManager.Text = "Disabled";
    }
    else {
      objRegistryKey.DeleteValue("DisableTaskMgr");
      lblTaskManager.Text = "Enabled";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy worked like a charm. Dont know why people just want to give you negative rating while all you're trying to do is learn.

Comment: First, you´re welcome. Second - some people are like that - we can´t change that. Third: If you accept one of the answers as answer, this would also be nice.